# Cannot connect to MySQL on local server

Tags: c#, mysql

I have recently installed MySQL on our local server, and I am attempting to connect to it using this connection string:

```
mySqlConnectionString = "server=192.168.1.254;database=dcim;uid=root;pwd=LlmD62jL;";
```

I have also tried adding the port as well:

```
mySqlConnectionString = "server=192.168.1.254:3306;database=dcim;uid=root;pwd=LlmD62jL;";
```

But I still keep getting the MySqlException:

> 1042 - Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL Hosts.

I have tried with the Firewall active and de-activated, but nothing has worked so far. What's going on?

EDIT: I thought I should note that I used this connection string to connect to MySQL on the same machine, with no problems using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

NB: This is MySQL Server with .NET Framework connection.

Comment: What's happen if you use `localhost` instead the IP address?

Comment: @sgmart same thing unfortunately

Comment: I'm guessing you have a trouble with your MySQL. Maybe is not running, so I suggest to try to connect to it through the command line: `mysql -u root -h localhost -p` or the IP instead localhost. So finally try to go to the c# way and use the same parameters like on cmd.

Comment: Which kind of platform are you using to connect; OLE DB, ODBC or .NET drivers? They all have different connection string and so you need to specify your drivers.

Comment: @Juniar I'm using .NET

Comment: @sgmart I've tried that in the cmd and I keep getting "mysql is not a valid directory"

Comment: This is a .NET with OLE DB driver connection string: Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;

Comment: You might be having problem with the Username: Whats the name of your Server it should be something like: root@locahost. And make sure your variable are all capitalized Example; "Server" capital "S", "Uid" capital "U", "Pwd" capital "P". Also you can connect with the TCP IP port.

Answer (score 1):

1. First **check mysql server is working or not**.
2. Try to **add port number** of mysql in connection string(The port 3306 is the default MySql port).
3. **Check spacing and Order of parameters** in connection string.(Sometimes it matters base on my experience",) )

Here's the basic format you could follow:

```
Server=ServerAddress; Port=1234; Database=DataBase; Uid=Username; Pwd=Password;
```

Also try to read this article its useful for connection strings. [MySQL connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

Hope it helps. ",)